# How to set options in FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I'm using `FluentValidation` in `ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API`. When there is a validation error, `FluentValidation` returns list of errors with field names (or `{PropertyName}`). The problem is it is normalizing them: For example UserId, is changed to "User Id". I want to keep the original property name in the error.

I found similar issue [here](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1294). The solution is: *"you can turn it off globally by setting ValidatorOptions.DisplayNameResolver to a custom function in your application’s startup routine."*. I also found this on their official website:

```
ValidatorOptions.DisplayNameResolver = (type, member, expression) => {
  if(member != null) {
     return member.Name + "Foo";
  }
  return null;
};
```

But my (rookie) question is: How can I add these options to my project?? This is my `Startup` class (`opt` doesn't have `DisplayNameResolver`):

```
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddFluentValidation(opt =>
            {
                opt.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining(typeof(PlayerInputValidator));
            });
```

Comment: `ValidatorOptions.DisplayNameResolver` is a static member, so you can configure it in `ConfigureServices` using the code you have posted, just put it outside the `services` configuration.

Comment: @stuartd oh.. is the order important? Should I `AddFluentValidation` first ?

Comment: I don't think it matters. The AddFluentValidation extension will be to add FV services etc to the DI container. The validation options are static and will be available at any point

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to set this globally in your Startup file:

```
FluentValidation.ValidatorOptions.Global.DisplayNameResolver = (type, member, expression) => member?.Name;
```

Another option is to use `.WithName` on the rule to specify the value for that case.